# Replace fabs in C++

Tags: c++

Is there any different function in C++, which I can replace function fabs()?
For example like this:

```
fabs(tab[j][i]) > fabs(tab[max][i])
```

Comment: Why do you need to replace it? It still works the same way it did in the early days of C.

Comment: Also, read the tag wikis more carefully, three out of four tags you used don't apply here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. [`abs` from `<cmath>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you still use `fabs` if the argument is always `double` - it is more reliable. The risk is: sometimes only `abs(int)` will be visible, so your `double` argument will be truncated to `int` (you may get a compiler warning, though).

One of the reasons is that until C++17 it is not guaranteed that a single header includes both `abs(int)` and `abs(double)`: `<cmath>` **must** contain `abs(double)` and `<cstdlib>` **must** contain `abs(int)`, but of course they **may** contain both. So, changing the compiler may change which overload is chosen.

Another example: if you `#include` `"math.h"` instead of `<cmath>`, and use Visual C++, will `abs(double)` be visible? It will be - up to Visual Studio 2013, but when you upgrade to Visual Studio 2015 you lose it.

Of course, use should still use `abs` when its argument type is not known, e.g. it is a part of a template.

Comment: Guarding against the inclusion of a header from the wrong language ?

Comment: @Quentin It was just an example, and not the best one. I will update the answer.